# Comparing two groups over two time points

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have two groups of participants ($A$ and $B$) who have been measured at two points in time ($T_0$ and $T_1$) for a continuous variable (a biomarker in the blood).

If I wanted to know if the change over time in the biomarker ($T_1-T_0$) was different between the group $A$ and $B$ I'd compare the change in each group with a $t$-test or similar. However, I want to know if any of the four means of $T_0(A)$, $T_1(A)$, $T_0(B)$, $T_1(B)$ are different from the others. If there were just four different groups I'd use a one way ANOVA, but the groups are related two-and-two. What can I use instead?

Comment: This seems perfectly clear to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two-factor (Factor 1 = group and Factor 2 = time) ANOVA with an interaction term between your two factors. Then conduct a post-hoc Tukey Honest Signficant Difference test to assess the mean differences. The interaction term in the ANOVA will allow you to compare all six mean differences with the post-hoc test.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky because some comparisons are between-subjects and some are within-subjects. You could test all pairwise comparisons using t tests (some paired, some not) and correct for multiple comparisons using some version of the Bonferroni correction. There is no need to precede this with any type of ANOVA since you will have controlled the Type I error rate.