# What test to choose

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to know if feedback given to treatment group will have any effect on their test score compared with a control group that doesn't get any feedback. It's a pretest posttest experiment. I think an independent samples t test should do but don't know how to handle the scores from the two tests. I'm a novice in stats

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You have two groups and two time points for each group. Maybe you should choose a design which would take this into account. Here is a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270400/comparing-two-groups-over-two-time-points