Two way ANOVA or two way repeat measurement ANOVA
I would like to compare two age group of people over two time point. Say, the temperature of children versus adult at 1st month and post 6-months respectively.
Dependent v: Temperature
Independent V: age group, time points.
Is this correct? Which method should I use and how my data will look like on Excel table? I am confused over how my table will look like.

Thanks alot to everyone for your inputs. It is my first time handling statistics and I have no prior background, hence I am stuck for very long.

Edit: Actually I need to answer the question of whether does high fever happen more often in younger or older group? (Just an example).

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270400/comparing-two-groups-over-two-time-points This is same questions as what I am intending to do.

Do you have repeated measures or not? If so, how many?
If you have repeated measures, you need to account for them, but I would generally opt for a multilevel model rather than RM ANOVA, which assumes sphericity. This is not usually a reasonable assumption.
If you don't have repeated measures, then a two way ANOVA seems reasonable. I would, however, avoid grouping age.
As for how your data looks, consult the manual for R or SAS or whatever statistical software you are using.

Yes I have repeated measurements. I have a sample size of 150. Hence, participant A would have 2 measurements, one at time point T1, and another at post 6-months later T6.

Do you have 2 observations from each participant? Meaning, are you measuring the same kids and same adults at 1 months and 6 months? If so, you should use a test that accounts for this repeated nature of temperature measurements, and repeated-measures ANOVA (or rather mixed ANOVA with time as a within-participant variable and age group as a between-participant variable) would be suitable, yes.
As for data arrangement and other specifics, you should check out tutorials on how to run a repeated-measures anova in the software you are using (Excel?).

Hi yes I am measuring the same kids and same adult at 1 month and 6 months respectively. It is a repeated measurement for same person. Hence person A would have 2 repeated interval measurement. I would have to look at tutorial at how to arrange my raw data into the Excel table. I am having difficulty arranging the raw data into the required table for repeated-measures ANOVA.

May I know whether is 2x2 ANOVA same as a repeated-measures ANOVA? I am confused.

"A repeated measures ANOVA is used to determine whether or not there is a statistically significant difference between the means of three or more groups in which the same subjects show up in each group." What if I only have two groups instead of three or more groups as defined? Can I still use repeated measures ANOVA?

First comment: in your Excel file, you should have one row for each participating person, one column for the 1 month measure, one column for the 6 month measure, and one column indicating whether the participant is child or adult. (typically you would also have a column for participant id number, if you have such, but that's not necessary for the analysis).

Second comment: these terms are often used in slightly different ways, but generally no. 2x2 ANOVA would most commonly refer to ANOVA with two between-subject factors and their interaction. Repeated-measures ANOVA refers to having a within-subject factor, like you have. But since you also have a between-subject factor (child vs. adult), you would be conducting something typically called mixed ANOVA (mixed as in both within and between factors).

Third comment: the formulation you quote most likely refers to the fact that if you only have two within-subject measurements, you can also use a paired-samples t-test instead of ANOVA. If you have 3 or more measurements, t-test won't work and you need ANOVA. You, however, can't use a paired-samples t-test (even though you only have two measurements) because you have the child vs. adult between-subjects variable in addition to the two repeated measurements. So a mixed ANOVA will work.

A multilevel model would also work, and they are more flexible as commented here, but you can't run one in Excel and they require some time and effort to learn (well what doesn't).

I don’t need to belabor the point that others have made but would recommend a Mixed Effects Model / Multilevel Model over a RM ANOVA for a variety of reasons.
Mixed Effects Models do not require complete data at all time points, do not require sphericity assumption, can account for multiple sources of variability (subject & stimulus for example), different amounts of timepoints between subjects, can flexibly handle non-parametric data, etc.
When is a repeated measures ANOVA preferred over a mixed-effects model?

Alright thanks alot. I will read up on Mixed Effects Model too. Initially my supervisor mentioned that I can use a repeated-measure ANOVA and then conduct a post-hoc Tukey Honest Significance Difference test to assess mean Difference. However, I am stuck at arranging raw data into the required analysis table for repeated measure ANOVA
